# How to return a list of words that occur n or more times in a text?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to write a function that takes a string **text** and a positive integer n, and converts text into a list of words. It must return a list of words and occur **n** or more times in **text**. I am trying to use a dictionary to accomplish this task.

What I want returned is in the following:

```
>>> repeat_word_count("buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo", 2)
['buffalo']
>>> repeat_word_count("one one was a racehorse two two was one too", 3)
['one']
>>> repeat_word_count("how much wood could a wood chuck chuck", 1)
['a', 'chuck', 'could', 'how', 'much', 'wood']
```

I have been using a dictionary to count how many times each word occurs in the text. This is what I have so far:

```
def repeat_word_count(text, n):

    my_string = text.split()
    my_dict = {}
    for word in my_string:
        if word in my_dict:
            my_dict[word] += 1
        else:
            my_dict[word] = 1

    for key, value in my_dict.items():
        if value >= n:
            return sorted(my_dict.keys())
```

I know that the second 'for' loop is not correct, but I don't know how to check if the values from **my_dict** are bigger or equal to **n**. So far my code is not working that well. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the final for loop with the following:

```
return [key for key, value in my_dict.items() if value >= n]
```

You can also sort if necessary:

```
result = [key for key, value in my_dict.items() if value >= n]
result.sort()
return result
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is using [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from the [collections](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#module-collections) module.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> def repeat_word_count(text, n):
...     return [key for key, value in Counter(text.split()).items() if value >= n]
... 
>>> repeat_word_count("buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo", 2)
['buffalo']
>>> repeat_word_count("one one was a racehorse two two was one too", 3)
['one']
>>> repeat_word_count("how much wood could a wood chuck chuck", 1)
['a', 'much', 'how', 'could', 'chuck', 'wood']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for others who want a more simplistic approach:

```
    def repeat_word_count(text, n):

        my_string = text.split()
        my_dict = {}
        for word in my_string:
            if word in my_dict:
                my_dict[word] += 1
            else:
                my_dict[word] = 1

        result = []
        for key, value in my_dict.items():
            if value >= n:
                result.append(key)
        return sorted(result)
```